# Maven: The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml, maven-jar-plugin, maven-install-plugin

I'm using Maven 3.0.3 on Mac 10.6.6.  I have a JAR project and when I run the command "mvn clean install:install", I'm getting the error,

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-cli) on project StarTeamCollisionUtil: The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact -> [Help 1]
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?  Below is my pom.xml.  Let me know what other info would be helpful and I'll edit this post.  Thanks, - Dave

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.myco.starteam.util</groupId>
<artifactId>StarTeamCollisionUtil</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>StarTeam Collision Util</name>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>myco-sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
        <name>MyCo Sonatype-Nexus Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://sonatype.myco.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 247, accepted):

I don't know if this is the answer or not but it might lead you in the right direction...

(I believe these steps are for people working with Intellij IDE. The [`install:install`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-mojo.html) is available in the Maven panel on the right by default. The below steps are alternative to it.)

The command [`install:install`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-mojo.html) is actually a goal on the [maven-install-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/). This is different than the `install` maven lifecycle phase.

[Maven lifecycle phases](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) are steps in a build which certain plugins can bind themselves to. Many different goals from different plugins may execute when you invoke a single lifecycle phase.

What this boils down to is the command...

```
mvn clean install
```

is different from...

```
mvn clean install:install
```

The former will run all goals in every cycle leading up to and including the install (like compile, package, test, etc.). The latter will not even compile or package your code, it will just run that one goal. This kinda makes sense, looking at the exception; it talks about:

> StarTeamCollisionUtil: The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact

Try the former and your error might just go away!

Comment: I am running through Bamboo, but I dont see anything mvn install:install any where in config

Answer (score 146):

**TL;DR** To fix this issue, invoke packaging plugin before, e.g. for `jar` packaging use `maven-jar-plugin` , as following:

```
mvn jar:jar install:install
```

Or

```
mvn jar:jar deploy:deploy
```

If you actually needed to deploy.

**Gotcha** This approach won't work if you have multi-module project with different packagings (ear/war/jar/zip) – even worse, wrong artifacts will be installed/deployed! In such case use reactor options to only build the deployable module (e.g. the `war`).

---

**Explanation**

In some cases you actually want to run directly a `install:install` or `deploy:deploy` goal (that is, from the `maven-deploy-plugin`, the `deploy` goal, not the Maven `deploy` [phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)) and you would end up in the annoying `The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact`.

A classic example is a CI job (a Jenkins or Bamboo job, e.g.) where in different steps you want to execute/care about different aspects:

- A first step would be a `mvn clean install`, performing tests and test coverage
- A second step would be a Sonarqube analysis based on a quality profile, e.g. `mvn sonar:sonar` plus further options
- Then, and only after successful tests execution and quality gate passed, you want to deploy to your Maven enterprise repository the final project artifacts, yet you don't want to re-run `mvn deploy`, because it would again execute previous phases (and compile, test, etc.) and you want your build to be effective but yet **fast**.

Yes, you could speed up this last step at least skipping tests (compilation and execution, via [`-Dmaven.test.skip=true`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#skip)) or play with a particular profile (to skip as many plugins as possible), but it is much easier and clear to simply run `mvn deploy:deploy` then.

But it would fail with the error above, because as also specified [by the plugin FAQ](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/faq.html#deploy_deploy):

> During the packaging-phase all gathered and placed in context. With this mechanism Maven can ensure that the `maven-install-plugin` and `maven-deploy-plugin` are copying/uploading the same set of files. So when you only execute `deploy:deploy`, then there are no files put in the context and there is nothing to deploy.

Indeed, the `deploy:deploy` needs some runtime information placed in the build context by previous phases (or previous plugins/goals executions).

It has also reported as a potential bug: **[`MDEPLOY-158`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEPLOY-158): deploy:deploy does not work for only Deploying artifact to Maven Remote repo**

But then rejected as not a problem.

The [`deployAtEnd`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#deployAtEnd) configuration option of the `maven-deploy-plugin` won't help neither in certain scenarios because we have intermediate job steps to execute:

> Whether every project should be deployed during its own deploy-phase or at the end of the multimodule build. If set to `true` and the build fails, none of the reactor projects is deployed. (experimental)

**So, how to fix it?**
Simply run the following in such a similar third/last step:

```
mvn jar:jar deploy:deploy
```

The `maven-jar-plugin` will not re-create any jar as part of your build, thanks to its [`forceCreation`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#forceCreation) option set to `false` by default:

> Require the jar plugin to build a new JAR even if none of the contents appear to have changed. By default, this plugin looks to see if the output jar exists and inputs have not changed. If these conditions are true, the plugin skips creation of the jar.

But it will nicely populate the build context for us and make `deploy:deploy` happy. No tests to skip, no profiles to add. Just what you need: speed.

---

Additional note: if you are using the `build-helper-maven-plugin`, `buildnumber-maven-plugin` or any other similar plugin to generate meta-data later on used by the `maven-jar-plugin` (e.g. entries for the Manifest file), you most probably have executions linked to the `validate` phase and you still want to have them during the `jar:jar` build step (and yet keep a fast execution). In this case the almost harmless overhead is to invoke the `validate` [phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Build_Lifecycle_Basics) as following:

```
mvn validate jar:jar deploy:deploy
```

---

Yet another additional note: if you have not `jar` but, say, `war` packaging, use `war:war` before install/deploy instead.

**Gotcha** as pointed out above, check behavior in multi module projects.

Comment: Ran into this exact scenario. Fantastic write up - should be in the deploy plugin FAQ instead of it's fairly terse "you can't do that" explanation.

Comment: Who would have thought that jar jar can be useful after all ;)

Comment: See my solution for mutli-module projects: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57824874/318174

Comment: this solution works fine for my multi-module project @AdamGent

Comment: Excellent explanation.  Described exactly my scenario with my Jenkins server.

Comment: {{jar:jar}} won't work unless you also have JAR sources in {{target}} along with the JAR archive.

Comment: Spent hours researching this, without luck, and this answer describes each and every detail perfectly. Thanks for this great summary.

Comment: You can also use `mvn jar:jar jar:test-jar install:install` if you also want to install tests.jar

Comment: "mvn jar:jar install:install"  ===> This has save a lot of mine time. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 29):

This reply is on a very old question to help others facing this issue.

I face this failed error while I were working on my **`Java`** project using <kbd>**`IntelliJ IDEA`**</kbd> IDE.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-cli) on project getpassword: The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact
```

this failed happens, when I choose `install:install` under `Plugins - install`, as pointed with red arrow in below image.

[image: Choose Wrong Selection]

Once I run the selected `install` under `Lifecycle` as illustrated above, the issue gone, and my maven install compile build successfully.

Answer (score 9):

This error shows up when using the maven-install-plugin version 3.0.0-M1 (or similar)

As already mentioned above and also here the following plug-in version works:

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Indeed the maven install and maven deploy plugin since version 3.0.0 require your project to have a main artifact if your project has `<packaging>jar</packaging>`. So if you have e.g. only tests in a project, this error will come up as well. Check if your project has the correct packaging, e.g. packaging `pom` if you only have a pom file. If you can't change the packaging, then as an ugly workaround you could add a dummy class in `src/main/java`. This will be compiled and deployed in the regular jar.

Comment: Thanks @JoepWeijers. I faced same issue (project with no class in `main/java` but only in `test/java`). Create a dummy class in `main/java` did the trick.

Comment: If you have only tests in your project you could simply define `test-jar` of `maven-jar-plugin` to [create a jar containing test classes](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html).

Answer (score 7):

I have same issue. 
Error message for me is not complete. But in my case, I've added generation jar with sources. By placing this code in pom.xml:

```
<build> 
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

So in deploy phase I execute source:jar goal which produces jar with sources. And deploy ends with BUILD SUCCESS

Answer (score 3):

For one of my multi-module projects, I legitimately didn't need to assign a file to the build artifact for the install phase, as a different plugin I use will do additional work to the jar to make it complete.

As of [maven-install-plugin v3.1.1](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-mojo.html) , you now have the option of "allowing incomplete projects", with the following config:

```
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <version>3.1.1</version>
      <configuration>
          <allowIncompleteProjects>true</allowIncompleteProjects>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Without it, `allowIncompleteProjects` is by default false.

Comment: In my case I used a `<classifier>` in maven-jar-plugin which leads to the error message. The `allowIncompleteProjects` configuration helped to install the artifact without errors.

Answer (score 2):

you must clear the target file such as in jar and others
In C: drive your folder at .m2 see the location where it install and delete the .jar file,Snaphot file and delete target files then clean the application you found it will be run

Comment: Well a partial solution.

Answer (score 2):

While @A_Di-Matteo answer does work for non multimodule I have a solution for multimodules.

The solution is to override every plugin configuration so that it binds to the phase of `none` with the exception of the jar/war/ear plugin and of course the deploy plugin. Even if you do have a single module my rudimentary tests show this to be a little faster (for reasons I don't know) performance wise.

Thus the trick is to make a profile that does the above that is activated when you only want to deploy.

Below is an example from one of my projects which uses the shade plugin and thus I had to re-override the jar plugin not to overwrite:

```xml
    <profile>
      <id>deploy</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>buildStep</name>
          <value>deploy</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>default-compile</id>
                <phase>none</phase>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>default-testCompile</id>
                <phase>none</phase>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>test-compile</id>
                <phase>none</phase>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>default-test</id>
                <phase>none</phase>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>default-install</id>
                <phase>none</phase>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>default-resources</id>
                <phase>none</phase>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>default-testResources</id>
                <phase>none</phase>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>default</id>
                <phase>none</phase>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>default-jar</id>
                <configuration>
                  <forceCreation>false</forceCreation>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
```

Now if I run `mvn deploy -Pdeploy` it will only run the jar and deploy plugins.

How you can figure out which plugins you need to override is to run deploy and look at the log to see which plugins are running. Make sure to keep track of the `id` of the plugin configuration which is parens after the name of the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Since maven-install-plugin 3.1.1 there is an [allowIncompleteProjects-toggle](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-mojo.html#allowIncompleteProjects)

```
<properties>
    <allowIncompleteProjects>true</allowIncompleteProjects>
</properties>
```

Our use-case (where changing packaging to pom doesn't work) is by using [maven-antrun-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html) referencing the maven classpaths...

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading mvn form `apache-maven-3.9.3` to `apache-maven-3.6.3` made the error disappear.Probably incompatibility issue with `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:3.1.1`.. play around with the versions if non of the above solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I executed **mvn install** initially (not **install:install** as it was mentioned earlier).

The solution is to include:

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
 </plugin>
```

Into plugin management section.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I got the same error message...

```
mvn install deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error occur when the plugins that are needed are not specifically mentioned in the pom. So

```
mvn clean install
```

will give the exception if this is not added:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
 </plugin>
```

Likewise,

```
mvn clean install deploy
```

will fail on the same exception if something like this is not added:

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.1</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>default-deploy</id>
         <phase>deploy</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>deploy</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

It makes sense, but a clearer error message would be welcome

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **properties** tag:

```
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

---

A working version of pom.xml file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>se-lab1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>
                                        org.hkr.Main
                                    </mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone but I accidentally added a module to my project and it changed my pom file from

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

to

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

so I just changed it back to

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

and it worked to create the jar again

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:3.0.1:install (default-install) on project MyProject: The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact -> [Help 1]
```

In my case, **the error was due to blank spaces in my project directory path** e.g.:

```
 ~\Documents\Job\My Project\my-project
```

I have renamed the directory in order to have a project path without blank spaces and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

#### Did you customize the maven-clean-plugin?

This was my example:

If you define a custom configuration of `maven-clean-plugin` removing additional directories generated during integration tests that should not be packaged, this might break the build:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-clean-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/refs</directory>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Why?** The plugin invocation happens in the `post-integration-test` phase that happens *after* running the tests (`integration-test`) but *berfore* checking and packaging (`verify` and `package`), the plugin by default removes the generated directory of the build.

In most cases, it is `target` defaults to `project.build.directory` and other properties, see more [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/). The consequence is that this misconfiguration breaks the build as there remains *nothing* to pack hence such an error.

**The solution** is to enable the `excludeDefaultDirectories` to exclude the plugin's default behavior and leave it to remove only what it was configured for.

```xml
<configuration>
    <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
    <filesets>
        <fileset>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/refs</directory>
        </fileset>
    </filesets>
</configuration>
```