# Maven - Install without compile

Tags: maven

Assume I have the jar under the target folder: Is there any option in maven to install into local repository jar without executing previous phases (compile, package)?

Comment: More info about this and the error "the packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact" in: [Maven: The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308162/maven-the-packaging-for-this-project-did-not-assign-a-file-to-the-build-artifac)

Answer (score 16):

Simply do `mvn install:install` instead of `mvn install`.

Comment: Is there anything similar for deploying without compile.

Comment: Yes, `mvn deploy:deploy`.

Comment: Doesn't work - `The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact` error.

Comment: That's correct because you run a goal, not a phase. the file is unknown to the build reactor.

Comment: See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38148135/543699) if you need to install the artifact without rebuilding.  TLDR; use: `mvn validate jar:jar install:install`.  It runs three (quick) phases, and does _not_ rebuild.

Answer (score 6):

Taken form the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
-DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

you need to run this once for the pom and once for the jar.

Comment: There is no need to do so if this is a project created file not 3rd party.