# Deploying maven artifacts without rebuilding

Tags: maven, jenkins-pipeline

We are using declarative pipeline, latest Jenkins. Builds are executed in a docker slave container, which has maven and other tools. Our current Jenkinsfile resembles this:

```
stage('build') { steps { sh 'mvn clean install'} }
stage('test') { /* functional tests using a different tool */ }
stage('publish') { 
    steps {
      // mvn clean deploy -DskipTests -DaltDeploymentRepository... (rebuilds, which we want to avoid, as its a multimodule project)
      // withMaven(options:[artifactsPublisher()] { } ... (from maven-pipeline-plugin)
    }
}
```

Jenkins classic mode has a Maven Integration plugin which provides a section "Deploy artifacts to Maven repository" which uses Maven RedeployPublisher to only publish artifacts. I am looking for a pipeline equivalent of this, I thought the maven-pipeline-plugin does this, but cant find an example. Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: The problem you are faced is that the maven life cycle runs all steps in case of using `deploy` which includes the `install` phase...The question is what kind of tool you are using for functional tests? Why not using integration-test phase of Maven ?

Comment: @khmarbaise yes and the install phase is what we want to avoid. The functional tests is also mvn based but has to run independently from compilation for other reasons.

Comment: @vasya10 did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: @filip not the way we wanted to. we continue to use mvn clean deploy command and skip tests, yes it rebuilds but publishes correctly.

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled upon your question looking for the same thing, and what worked for me was this:

```
stage('Deploy') {
    sh "'${mvnHome}/bin/mvn' war:war deploy:deploy"
}
```

Of course, you need to change war:war to the type of the artifact that you want to deploy (so `jar:jar` or `ear:ear`). I found this basing on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38148135/4301003), but it seems to be relevant to `maven-war-plugin`, as well as to `maven-jar-plugin`, although there is no [forceCreation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#forceCreation) option in the `war` goal.

Comment: In this way you deploy only the specified artifacts? How would you deploy (without rebuilding) all artifacts (jars, zip,...) of a multi-module project?

Comment: I'm afraid that this doesn't work for multi-module projects. My suggestion would be to use `mvn deploy -DskipTests` (without `clean` phase) after `mvn clean install`.

Comment: @bushi While `mvn deploy -DskipTests` works it rebuilds the entire project. It's really ironic that Maven and Jenkins integrate so poorly.

Answer (score 0):

A late answer, but there is actually a goal in the Maven Deploy plugin specifically for this use case: `deploy:deploy-file`.

This exists to deploy an existing file, without any rebuilding. Documentation can be found [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html).

An example usage (I didn't test it though):

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=file:/path-to-your/repo/ -Dfile=your-artifact-1.0.jar 
                       -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=my-artifact -Dpackaging=jar 
                       -Dversion=1.0 -DrepositoryId=your-repo-id
```